# Team Build Errors when there aren't any

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

I have a nightly team build that is reporting errors from the test step but zero errors in the summary.  This results in a partial success.

[alt text http://jonesie.net.nz/content/binary/buildsnip.jpg](http://jonesie.net.nz/content/binary/buildsnip.jpg)

I cant see any errors in the full build log but maybe it's just the quantity of warnings??

Anyone got any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The Running tests task failed....if any non-essential task fails, this results in a `Partially Succeeded` status.  Can you post the MSBuild file being used, specifically the `Running tests` section?

That being said, you should always pay attention to the warnings and resolve them whenever possible...**they are warnings for a reason**.  They often alert you to unintended behavior in your code (e.g. a property that doesn't override properly).

Comment: There are zero errors from the tests

  <TestContainer Include="$(OutDir)\%2a.Tests.dll" />


but there are a few warnings, eg:

  TESTTOOLSTASK : Instrumentation warning : cannot find binary C:\build\PROJECT\Integration\Binaries\Debug\product.Cache.dll.
  TESTTOOLSTASK : warning VSP2013: Instrumenting this image requires it to run as a 32-bit process.  The CLR header flags have been updated to reflect this.

I'll clean these up and see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try searching for the string "error :" in the log file.

MSBuild will automatically generate an error if it sees this string in the output anywhere.

So even if the string happens to be "error : 0" (as in everything is just peachy), MSBuild will still exit with an error!

This issue has also been documented here:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/msbuild/thread/77eb8b02-8cd7-4d32-acad-3ab0dc308d78/